# Using Fetch on a Non-Existent Row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch, statements

I've been stuck for a while now.
This code works for the most part, however there is a small issue. When I request a username that doesn't exist in my table, the script fails at `$stmt->fetch()`. It looks bad on the website when the script can't return an actual "invalid username/password" message and instead basically dies.

```
if($stmt = $DB_CON -> prepare("SELECT `ID`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`, `Access`, `Banned` FROM `users` WHERE `Username`=?")) {
if(!($stmt -> bind_param('s', $USERNAME))){
    die($stmt->error); //These return empty...
}
if(!($stmt -> execute())){
    die($stmt->error);
}
if(!($stmt -> store_result())){
    die($stmt->error);
}
if(!($stmt -> bind_result($ID, $USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $EMAIL, $ACCESS, $BANNED))){
    die($stmt->error);
}
if(!($stmt -> fetch())){
    die($stmt->error);
}
```

What am I missing/need to change?

Comment: remove `die($stmt->error);` and the script will continue and not display an error. You are telling the script to stop processing and display the error.

Comment: Wow. (facepalm) I can't believe how easy that was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rasclatt, the solution was to just remove the `if(!( ... ))` portion from the script, as it was killing when it couldn't return information.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes the answer is staring at you and it takes fresh eyes to see it! Cheers